# How to install Spark 2.1.0 on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and am following [this blog](https://x86x64.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/installing-spark-on-windows/) to install Spark 2.1.0.

So I tried to build Spark from the sources that I'd cloned from https://github.com/apache/spark to `C:\spark-2.1.0`.

When I run `sbt assembly` or `sbt -J-Xms2048m -J-Xmx2048m assembly`, I get:

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\spark-2.1.0\project
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to C:\spark-2.1.0\project\target\scala-2.10\sbt-0.13\classes...
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at scala.reflect.api.Printers$class.render(Printers.scala:168)
at scala.reflect.api.Universe.render(Universe.scala:59)
at scala.reflect.api.Printers$class.show(Printers.scala:190)
at scala.reflect.api.Universe.show(Universe.scala:59)
at scala.reflect.api.Printers$class.treeToString(Printers.scala:182)
...
```

I adapted the memory settings of sbt as suggested, which are ignored anyway. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked blog post was "Posted on April 29, 2015" that's 2 years old now and should only be read to learn how things have changed since (I'm not even going to link the blog post to stop directing people to the site).

The 2017 way of installing Spark on Windows is as follows:

1. Download Spark from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html.
2. Read the official documentation starting from [Downloading](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#downloading).

That's it.

### Installing Spark on Windows

Windows is known to give you problems due to Hadoop's requirements (and Spark does use Hadoop API under the covers).

You'll have to install `winutils` binary that you can find at https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils repository.

TIP: You should select the version of Hadoop the Spark distribution was compiled with, e.g. use hadoop-2.7.1 for Spark 2.1.0.

Save `winutils.exe` binary to a directory of your choice, e.g. `c:\hadoop\bin` and define `HADOOP_HOME` to include `c:\hadoop`.

See [Running Spark Applications on Windows](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html) for further steps.

Comment: Thanks. Mmmh I tried this but had issues as download is not build for 64bit machine. Hence I tried to build it via sbt. Why oh why is it so hard to get this running ...

Comment: What issues do you have with the official Spark distro (after you unpack it and run `run-example SparkPi`)? That's your **real** issue I suppose.

Comment: For starters: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable ... see this post, which made me try to build it form scratch.

Comment: Don't do this (and it's not for starters). Why do you need the builtin-java classes for? I don't. And it's from Hadoop not Spark (so you should be building Hadoop instead).

Comment: Ok after another try I got it running hurray. Thanks. Next decision: use R, Python, Scala or C# to access this (-:

Answer (score 0):

The following settings worked for me (sbtconfig.txt):

```
# Set the java args to high

-Xmx1024M

-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

-Xss2M

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m

# Set the extra SBT options

-Dsbt.log.format=true
```

Comment: This answer may help you should you decide to build it from scratch. Please see @Jacek Laskowski answer though.